# Python (lambda?) random number generation

Tags: python

I have a string where I want to output random ints of differing size using Python's built-in format function.

IE:  "{one_digit}:{two_digit}:{one_digit}"
Yields:  "3:27:9"

I'm trying:

```
import random

"{one_digit}:{two_digit}:{one_digit}".format(one_digit=random.randint(1,9),two_digits=random.randint(10,99))
```

but this always outputs...

```
"{one_digit}:{two_digit}:{one_digit}".format(one_digit=random.randint(1,9),two_digit=random.randint(10,99))
>>>'4:22:4'

"{one_digit}:{two_digit}:{one_digit}".format(one_digit=random.randint(1,9),two_digit=random.randint(10,99))
>>>'7:48:7'

"{one_digit}:{two_digit}:{one_digit}".format(one_digit=random.randint(1,9),two_digit=random.randint(10,99))
>>>'2:28:2'

"{one_digit}:{two_digit}:{one_digit}".format(one_digit=random.randint(1,9),two_digit=random.randint(10,99))
>>>'1:12:1'
```

Which is as expected since the numbers are evaluated before hand.  I'd like them to all be random, though.  I tried using a lambda function but only got this:

```
"test{number}:{number}".format(number=lambda x: random.randint(1,10))
```

But that only yields

```
"test{number}:{number}".format(number=lambda x: random.randint(1,10))

>>>'test<function <lambda> at 0x10aa14e18>:<function <lambda> at 0x10aa14e18>'
```

Comment: You are repeating 1st and 3rd. Just make them separate!

Comment: @AntonvBR this is a simplified example - for what I'm doing, I have to have hundreds of random integers in the string, making it cumbersome to have separate variables for each.

Comment: Show me your expected output and I'll help you!

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to do.. but you can just pass enough random numbers to format? `"test{}:{}".format(*random.sample(range(1,11), 2))`

Comment: @AntonvBR `2,-36,-400,5,1,9,1,4,8,3,7,5,2012945834811,-104890,58004,5,5,3205,6,2,4,9,8,4,09,-7,-9,7682880,3,-12,-053,2,5,8,-75,-684,-6,8,-75,-697,1,0,1,4,8,4,6-6,3,-95,-98,-0,4,-84,-22,07,7,-43,-758,27738278,3,-12,-065,60823,4,-23`

Comment: @miradulo I'm pretty sure you want `random.choices(range(1,11), k=2)` (to choose with replacement rather than without). But otherwise, to the extent that I think I know what the OP wants here, I think you've got the right answer.

Comment: @abarnert Oh oops, yes! I reach for `np.random` usually so I keep forgetting the `random` functions -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: `str.format` is the wrong tool for the job, because it doesn't allow you to generate a different value for each replacement.

The correct solution is therefore to implement your own replacement function. We'll replace the `{one_digit}` and `{two_digit}` format specifiers with something more suitable: `{1}` and `{2}`, respectively.

```
format_string = "{1}:{2}:{1}"
```

Now we can use regex to substitute all of these markers with random numbers. Regex is handy because [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) accepts a replacement function, which we can use to generate a new random number every time:

```
import re

def repl(match):
    num_digits = int(match.group(1))
    lower_bound = 10 ** (num_digits - 1)
    upper_bound = 10 * lower_bound - 1
    random_number = random.randint(lower_bound, upper_bound)
    return str(random_number)

result = re.sub(r'{(\d+)}', repl, format_string)
print(result)  # result: 5:56:1
```

Comment: Awesome!  Exactly what I need

Comment: Accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

What about This?

```
'%s:%s:%s' % (random.randint(1,9),random.randint(10,99),random.randint(1,9))
```

EDIT : meeting requirements.

```
a=[1,2,2,1,3,4,5,9,0] # our definition of the pattern (decimal range)
b= ''
for j in enumerate(a):
    x=random.randint(10**j,10**(j+1)-1)
    b = b + '%s:' % x
print(b)
```

sample:

> > > print (b)
> > >       31:107:715:76:2602:99021:357311:7593756971:1:

Comment: It works yep, but I have lots and lots of numbers to generate - here is a sample of the string I need to output (this is 1/8th of it) `2,-36,-400,5,1,9,1,4,8,3,7,5,2012945834811,-104890,58004,5,5,3205,6,2,4,9,8,4,09,-7,-9,7682880,3,-12,-053,2,5,8,-75,-684,-6,8,-75,-697,1,0,1,4,8,4,6-6,3,-95,-98,-0,4,-84,-22,07,7,-43,-758,27738278,3,-12,-065,60823,4,-23`

Comment: got it! I modified the answer with the proper code.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
import random

r = [1,2,3,4,5]

','.join(map(str,(random.randint(-10**i,10**i) for i in r)))
```

The first two params(-10** i, 10**i) are low and upper bound meanwhile size=10 is the amount of numbers).

Example output: `'-8,45,-328,7634,51218'`

---

Explanation:

It seems you are looking to join random numbers with `,`. This can simply be done using `','.join([array with strings])`, e.g. `','.join(['1','2'])` which would return `'1,2'`.

Comment: It works, but the issue is that they are all between -10000 and 10000, which makes always a 4 digit number.  I need differing ranges all over the place like in my pasted example.

Comment: I want to define them like in my example, {one_digit},{seven_digit},{twelve_digit} etc

Comment: @dmcmulle A very easy way to do this would be to put the values in an array and then loop through them. 2 lines and that's it.

Comment: @dmcmulle You accepted a really strange answer in my opinion. But if you are happy with it that's fine!!! :)